FirebaseCoreInternal 1 issue, Command SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface failed with a nonzero exit code
After upgrading my React Native project, I'm encountering the following error in Xcode during the build process:

FirebaseCoreInternal 1 issue, Command SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface failed with a nonzero exit code

I've tried changing the Swift Language versions 4.2, 5, and even 6 in  Xcode, but none of these resolved the issue.
Has anyone encountered this error before? How can I resolve this and successfully build the project in Xcode?

Did you find any solution?
